# Array element point float getting truncated

Tags: java, arrays, types, primitive, primitive-types

**Double** happens:

```
double ages[] = new double[] {2D, 3D, 4D, 5D};
ages[0] = 7/2;
```

```
Index  Element
0      3.0    
1      3.0
2      4.0
3      5.0
```

Makes sense because:

> 7 int / 2 int = 3 int

But when it gets **appended** at the final the suffix **D** or **F** to `ages[0] = 7/2;`, **INDEX 0** appears with decimals even when we are dividing integers:

```
double ages[] = new double[] {2D, 3D, 4D, 5D};
ages[0] = 7/2D;
```

```
Index  Element
0      3.5
1      3.0
2      4.0
3      5.0
```

Why its getting **truncated** even if the suffix **D** suppose to be "OPTIONAL"?

Comment: `1/3` is `0`. Because `int`/`int` is an `int`. The fact that you widen that `int` to `float` or a `double` doesn't give an `int` more precision. `(double) (1/3)` is still zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`7 / 2` is the `int/int` operation and therefore the result is `3`. When you assign it to a `float` or `double` variable, it will become `3.0`.

Comment: Can you resolve the new query that I edited in the post, please?

Comment: @Pablo_06 -  `7 / 2D = 3.5` because it's `int / double` operation. You can also write it as `7 / 2.0` which will also give you `3.5`. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Comment: So in this case, "D" is not optional?

Comment: I learned suffix "D" should be optional.

Comment: I've already mentioned it in my comment above.

Comment: @Pablo_06 It is optional in the literal `2.0D` (`2.0` works as well), but it is required in the literal `2D`, because the literal `2` is an `int` literal, not a `double` literal.